# IONIC- Module parse failed, Loading template

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have worked on a project and after updating the scripts, I find this error.
It seems like it is unable to convert the HTML files properly.
I've uninstalled ionic reinstalled everything to the latest versions but still giving the same error.

> Module parse failed: /Users/george/dev/flask/rdan/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack/loader.js!/Users/george/dev/flask/rdan/src/pages/home/home.ts Unexpected token (20:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | @Component({
>   |   selector: 'page-home',template:/*ion-inline-start:"/Users/george/dev/flask/rdan/src/pages/home/home.html"*/'\n\n  \n

This is my ionic info.

> global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3 Build version 8E162
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
npm        : 5.3.0
```

And this is the package.json file

```
{
"name": "rdan",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "^1.4.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
}
```

}

I've tried...

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall cordova -g
rm -rf node-modules
npm install
npm remove -g cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Any ideas?
Note: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The error reported a position (20: 0) which was commented out in the file home.js, and I was not paying attention thinking that the generated index.js is working etc ...

Finally I removed the code that occupied those lines (which I have already said was commented) and everything works again after two crazy days.